# How can I open all files in vs 2010 at the bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Suppose with VS  2010 I open a file contained in my project. It shows the top few lines like 1 , 2 ,3 , ...

I want to set something so that if I open a file, the editor is focused on the bottom lines. So if the file contains 5675 lines, focus is on line 5675.

Can I do this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull down the **Edit** menu, select **Go To**, type in **5675**, and click OK.

Or, do a **Ctrl-End**.

Comment: You could save a few mouse clicks and just type Ctrl+End.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the options available in Visual Studio 2010 or currently in the Extension Gallery.  You'll probably have to write a Visual Studio 2010 extension for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go to the bottom? Is it because a particular method is defined there? You might prefer to use the Class View to the Solution Explorer. Double-clicking in the solution explorer just opens the file, showing the top page of it. Double-clicking in the class view scrolls the file to the method you double-clicked on.